# The method cancel was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, provider

hello everyone hope you're doing well, 
I want to cancel a stream subscription, this is what i want to do

```
class classA extends ChangeNotifer{
StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream;
}

class classB extends State<Home>{

 Provider.of<classA>(context,listen: false).positionStream.cancel();
}
```

but it doesn't work and i get this error: 
cancel method was called on null

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not initiating this positionStream, that's why you are getting this error.

you can check null aware operator to avoid this error.

```
Provider.of<classA>(context,listen: false).positionStream?.cancel();  // Question mark added
```

Now, it will cancel stream only if it is not null.

Comment: congratz on 10k!

Comment: Thank you. @peterHaddad